# How do I install IIS management console?

Tags: iis, windows-7

I just installed Windows 7 Enterprise along with some development tools.  I didn't see IIS  (the management console) anywhere in the start menu.  I went to Turn Windows Features On or Off and saw that indeed IIS was present.  Even http://localhost/ responded.  I even turned all IIS features off (uninstalled them) and back on (rebooting each time).  I still don't get IIS on my start menu.

I also tried just launching MMC and adding the IIS snap-in, but that too, is absent.

How can I manage the IIS on my box?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doh!  I guess it's just an unchecked (and strangely non-default) feature: Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS Management Console.

I'd seen it before, but didn't think it was relevant as *Web* Management Tools suggests to me a web-based management interface.  Misnomer I guess.

Answer (score 8):

**Protip**: Start -> Run -> `inetmgr`

Bonus points for WinKey+R !

Answer (score 2):

Install the Internet Information Services (IIS 7) from the Web Platform Installer 3.0. link: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx Then, you would be able to find out the IIS Manager from the Administration Tools.